# Can't access HTTP server, but ping works in LAN

Tags: linux, ip, tcpip, tcp, static-ip

I encounter a problem when configure the connection. My computer resides in a LAN, I want to assign it a static IP address.

Thus with the help of port mapping on the router, I will be able to access my box from outside.

I modified the configuration file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and `ifconfig` shows a static IP `192.168.1.120` has already been bound to my machine. From another computer in the same LAN, I can ping `192.168.1.120` but fail to access the HTTP server on `192.168.1.120`(sure the HTTP service is up).

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description you are most likely on Redhat/Fedora/CentOS system.
If you are on these system goto shell and type ntsysv and select the firewall configuration. You need to allow http in the firewall. I'm sure you can do the same via GUI tool in GNome.